# Javascript Error: this.replace($foo, "");

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

My sixth line of code does not work.  Please help.

```
function ajax() {
    $('a[class="ajax-cw"]').click( function() {
        $('#cw').load( this + "?ajax" );
        $('#nav li.current').removeClass('current');
        var $base = $("base").attr("href"),
            $link = this.replace($base, ""); //Line does not work
        alert ($link);
        return false;
    });
};
```

Comment: Please provide more information when you're asking questions. Does it cause an error or just don't do anything? What's values of `this`, `$base` and `$link`? What do you get in `$link`? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Variables can be a list of comma seperated values, so that's probably not the issue. Try `console.log($base)` to see that you are actually getting the href of the base element (that noone uses anymore). Also, is'nt `this` a DOM element, how do you intend to replace that, it's not a string you know ???

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's `this.replace` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

if you were trying to replace parts of the href contents of the currently clicked link with that of the base object, you have to access the href contents via

```
var currenthref = $(this).attr('href');
```

and then use currenthref in the replace line.

```
$link = currenthref.replace($base, "");
```

Thre replace function on this will not properly work because it is not a string but rather an object (most likly jquery) that represents the link element you klicked on.

Comment: As far as I know, the JS DOM element referenced in `this` has no method attr(). Try wrapping some jQuery around it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.href.replace($base, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in line 6 is the `<a />` tag, not the href of that tag.  `$(this).attr('href').replace($base,"")` will perform better.

Answer (score -1):

You need to end the previous line with a semi-colon. You have ended it with a comma.

```
var $base = $("base").attr("href");
```

Comment: I think you're wrong. It's ok to declare multiple variables in single `var` expression separating them with a comma.

Comment: OK. Never used that. this references the hyperlink object on which there is no method replace but I wasn't clear on what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PorridgeBear: Actually, it's perfectly appropriate to use a comma to separate multiple expressions in appropriate situations. "Never use that" isn't really the appropriate advice here.